# Debugging while app is not running

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to debug (breakpoints) my app via Xcode if it's not running already and was launched as a result of swiping a remote notification from the locked screen?

Obviously I can't just add breakpoints and expect execution to halt since I need to fire the app via Xcode in order to debug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can launch the app in Xcode but set the scheme to wait for an external launch trigger. In this mode Xcode will watch and wait for something else to open the app.

To do this, edit the scheme, select the `info` section and then select `Wait for executable to be launched`.